# python error when added a function to a class

Tags: python-2.7

i just added this function to my class

```
def getTotalPopulation():
        print 'there are {0} people in the world'.format(Person.population)
```

when i call it, i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method getTotalPopulation() must be called with Person instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

I call it like this:

```
 from MyTests import Person
>>> Person.Person.getTotalPopulation()
```

#### for people who need all code

```
class Person:
    population = 0
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        Person.population += 1
        print '{A} has been born'.format(A = self.name)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} is {1} years old'.format(self.name, self.age)
    def __del__(self):
        Person.population -=1
        print '{0} is dying :( '.format(self.name)
    def getTotalPopulation():
        print 'there are {0} people in the world'.format(Person.population)
```

Comment: Why are you using a class while calling methods directly on it? Normally you'd create an instance first..

Comment: @MartijnPieters: because he's a Java programmer.

Comment: @Wooble amazing buddy, yes I like JAVA a lot. you cleaver

Comment: @MartijnPieters because I want to test class functions in python.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: Right, then IfLoop's answer is the way to go. It helped that you now posted your code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters no it didn't work

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: What, the `@classmethod`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters there is no class method, i was just trying `ifloops` answer

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: Did you read the latest revision at all?

Answer (score 1):

you need to make that a classmethod:

change

```
 class Person:
     def getTotalPopulation(self):
         return Person.population
```

to:

```
 class Person(object):
     @classmethod
     def getTotalPopulation(cls):
         return cls.population
```

that is, add the `@classmethod` decorator right before the `def`.  additionally, the first parameter of a classmethod is conventionally spelled `cls` instead of `self`; and you should use it in the method body to support subclasses properly.

That's for python 2, though.  For python three, your code works correctly, because methods can be used implicitly as though they are `staticmethod`s.  I wouldn't particularly reccomend that, though, since you almost never need that feature, but `classmethod`s are terrifically useful.

Comment: the tutorial didn't say that. he said like i make my code. also, my function doesn't pass `self` as an argument

Comment: is it necessery to be at the top of other functions?

Comment: Which tutorial; and could it be that you are following a tutorial for python 3 when you are using python 2 (or visa versa?)

Comment: i am using python 2.7 and this is the tutorials http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gGMwx9JHpWc

Comment: Looks like you are following a Python 3 tutorial; python 2 and 3 are very different languages, and learning either with mismatched versions will confuse you greatly;  make sure you are using the right version.

Comment: what is the solution if you know that i am using 2.7 python please?

Comment: the solution in my latest edit is idiomatic for both python 2 and 3;  you shouldn't ever need `staticmethod`; i certainly never have!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `self` for instance methods

```
def getTotalPopulation(self):
```

Comment: The OP is calling the method *on the class*. It's an unbound method.

Comment: @Martijn Then he has to pass an instance ``Person()`` , but there are other more logical possibilities, such as the ones I gave in my answer and @IfLoop too

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person(object):
    population = 102
    def getTotalPopulation(self):
            print '{0} people'.format(self.population)
Person.getTotalPopulation(Person())


class Person(object):
    population = 2458
    @classmethod
    def getTotalPopulation(cls):
            print '{0} people'.format(cls.population)
Person.getTotalPopulation()


class Person(object):
    population = 3548799
    @staticmethod
    def getTotalPopulation():
            print '{0} people'.format(Person.population)
Person.getTotalPopulation()
```

result

```
102 people
2458 people
3548799 people
```